# Python .pop() changes local list globally?

Tags: python, list, global, local

I came across a error in my code and after searching found that the .pop() function changes a list value in a local function, on a global level, without using return function or global statement. I understand what pop does, I've used it before, but I don't understand why it's affecting the value of list globally. Why is that? Is there a name for this and are there other functions that does the same?

```
#Example code
listname=[1,2,3,4,5]

def checkpop(listname):
    popped = listname.pop()
    listname = ['WTF']
    print (listname)

print(listname)
checkpop(listname)
print(listname)
```

## OUTPUT

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

['WTF']

[1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: This is expected behavior. It is absolutely not WTF. It is supposed to mutate the list in place. If you want to get the last element of a list use popped = listname[-1] instead.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "local list". There are local variables, but the objects they refer to aren't attached to any variable or scope.

Comment: The *object* is neither local nor global. The *variable* is. The local variables references the same object as the global variable. *Any* modification to that object being referenced locally will still be visible to global references. So all the list mutator methods would work this way, e.g. `list.append`,`list.extend`, `list.clear`, `list.sort`, etc.

Comment: @BeatrixKidco check this excellent blog post on python variables: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because assignments do not make any new copy of any object in Python. So, when you pass the *global* list as the argument to the function, you are binding to the same list object inside the function.

As lists are mutable in Python, when you do a in-place operation in it, you are changing the same *global* list object.

To get a better grasp, you can always check the `id`:

```
In [45]: lst = [1, 2]

In [46]: def foo(lst):
    ...:     print(id(lst))
    ...:     return   

In [47]: id(lst)
Out[47]: 139934470146568

In [48]: foo(lst)
139934470146568
```

Comment: Yep, an example is a good idea. You could just do https://ideone.com/DRhDI0 though and use `is` since it does the same thing as comparing `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your making a false distinction between the object the `listname` *variable* refers to and the object the `listname` *parameter* refers to.

The `listname` variable is like a tag. It is simply a reference to the list object `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. ***When you passed `listname` into `checkpop`, you gave the `listname` parameter a reference to the same list object the `listname` variable refers to***. The point here, is that the *`listname` variable and the `listname` parameter point to the same object*. Thus, mutating the object the `listname` parameter refers to, *will also* change the object that the global `listname` variable refers to.